# I've written code where I loop a random - the code works but now I want to add strings between every new number

Tags: python

I have written code where I loop a `random.randint`. The code works fine, but now I want to add strings between every new number and not print all the numbers at the same time and turn it to a board game. I am new to coding hope someone can help me and avoid typos or humiliating me.

This is my code

```
   import random
   for i in range(20):
   dice=random.randint(1,6)
   print(dice)
```

I have tried making separate for loops with range (1) but again they print numbers together when I run the code the numbers still print together and I don't know how to stop it. I even tried using a return function but then there is a syntax error

```
import random

for i in range(1):
    dice = random.randint(1,6)
    print(dice)

for i in range(1):
    dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
    print(dice2)

for i in range(1):
    dice3 = random.randint(1,6)
    print(dice3)

for i in range(1):
    dice4 = random.randint(1,6)
    print(dice4)

for i in range(1):
    dice5 = random.randint(1,6)
    print(dice5)

for i in range(1):
    dice6 = random.randint(1,6)
    print(dice6)

for i in range(1):
    dice7 = random.randint(1,6)
    print(dice7)
```

I have an idea to do something related slicing but I am not sure

Comment: **(1)** If you want to do something several times, put it into a loop, don't just repeat the code. (It is possible to put loops into other loops.) **(2)** `for i in range(1)` runs the contained code exactly once, so the loop is unnecessary. **(3)** If you want characters between your numbers, e.g. `1-3-4-2` then you have to write code that does this, e.g. `print("-")`.

Answer (score -1):

I‘m sorry, I didn‘t completely get your issue. But maybe you didn‘t convert the random int to a string? You have to do this to print something. Like this:

```
import random
for i in range(20):
    dice = random.randint(1, 6)
    # now convert it to a string to print it with str()
    print(str(dice))
```

I hope this was helpful :)